# Save a form with ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, forms

How can I pass any $_Post[''] with ajax to the php function, when the form is submitted?

The function is working with AJAX but it can't receive the post's values.
I tested and the alert return null.

I am using wordpress.

```
window.onload=function(){

jQuery('#newIdeaForm').submit(function(events){

    call_ajax(events);
    events.preventDefault();    
    }); 


  };    

function call_ajax(){

var name = $("#name").val(); 
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
    data: {action : 'savedata'},
    success: function(response) {


        var json = jQuery.parseJSON(response); 
        alert(json.nome);


    }
});

 };

function savedata(){

$name =  $_POST['name'];
$my_post = array(
            'post_title'    => 'teste',
            'post_content'  => 'teste',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_author'   => $user_id,
            );
        wp_insert_post($my_post);

        $callback = array('name' =>'teste','title'=>'teste','idea'=>'teste','nome' => $name);
        $myJson = json_encode($callback);
        echo ($myJson);
        die();
    }
```

EDITED

Man, I've tried like this:

```
 function call_ajax(){ 
 var serializedForm = jQuery('#newIdeaForm').serialize(); 
 serializedForm.action = 'savedata'; 
 jQuery.ajax({ 
 type: 'POST', 
 url: myAjax.ajaxurl, 
 data: serializedForm, 
 success: function(data) { 
 alert(data); 
 } 

 });
```

but it seems that it don't add anything like action when I debug via browser, so it don't go to the php function, anyone can help me?

Comment: Try `alert(response.nome);`

Comment: are you calling `savedata()` in php? Also, set `dataType:'json'`...don't need to use `parseJSON` then

Comment: If I use dataType :'json' the response will be already parsed?

Answer (score 1):

In the ajax call you are passing data which is converted to action=savedata which, but in the PHP you are trying to get 'name' from the POST data. With your ajax request, the form data is not automatically sent, so you either need to manually send it like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
  data: {action: 'savedata', name: name},
  sucess: ...
```

or use the .serialize() jQuery function which will automatically serialize the data in a form for you (which you can then supply as the data argument).

Comment: If I use serialize, how can I send the serialized form?
like this?
data: {action: 'savedata', form: serializedForm}

?

Comment: The way you gave would work, as long as you are aware that to access the data from php you need to use something like $_REQUEST['form']['name'], alternatively you could created the serialized form, and then do serializedForm.action = 'savedata' before sending the data. (and just use serializedForm as the data option).

Comment: That sounds nice, I will try it now!

Comment: Man, I've tried like this:

function call_ajax(){

 var serializedForm = jQuery('#newIdeaForm').serialize();
 serializedForm.action = 'savedata';
 jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
  data: serializedForm,
  success: function(data) {
   
   
   alert(data);


  }
 });
 

but it seems that it don't add anything like action when I debug via   browser, so it don't go to the php function.

Answer (score 1):

If this is what you are executing, I can't find you posting a key named "name".

```
function call_ajax(){

  var name = $("#name").val(); 
  jQuery.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
     data: {action : 'savedata', name: 'namevalue'},
     success: function(response) {
              var json = jQuery.parseJSON(response); 
              alert(json.nome);
     }
  });

};
```

Also have a look at:

[jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Hope this works. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Man, I didn't even tried yet, because I realized that serialize the form is the best option, now I'm trying to discover how to call the acion 'savedata' and pass the serialized form.

Answer (score 1):

try serialising your data and provide content type "application/json; charset=utf-8" like

```
 var url="@Url.Action("action","Controller")";
 var jsonSerialized=JSON.stringify(data);
 $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: url,
         dataType: "json",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         data: jsonSerialized,
         success: function (result) {
              alert(result);
        }
});
```

Comment: for url in url assign var url="@Url.Action("action","Controller")";

Comment: Sorry but I did not understand this. Could you be more specific?

Comment: where url is the url of your php function